# How set UIButton size by it's title size?

Tags: swift, uibutton, cgsize

I have UIButton, which title is dynamic changes. Button size should changes with title size and will be equal title size.

How to do this programmatically in Swift?

Answer (score 9):

To have your button use its *intrinsic content size* and automatically resize based upon its text, use *Auto Layout* to position the button.  Only set constraints to position the button and iOS will use the size of the text to determine the width and height of the button.

For example:

```
let button = UIButton()

// tell it to NOT use the frame
button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

button.setTitle("Hello", for: .normal)
view.addSubview(button)

button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
```

This also works if you create the button in the Storyboard.  Again, only give constraints to place the button and it will resize to accommodate the text.

Answer (score 2):

Follow below steps(its not a proper solution but you can solve your problem by doing like this )

1. Create a UILabel (because UILabel adjust its height and width depends on the text)
2. UIlabel number of line to 1
3. Create a UIButton over UILabel
4. Set button title to ""
5. Set button's constraint : Align button's top and leading to UILabel and equals width and height

Hope this will works for you :)

Comment: it ok, but what if I want to get pressed effect for text, when pressed button?
When I set button title and press but I have this effect

Answer (score 2):

You can get `UIButton's` `width` and `Height` dynamically with its `title`.

With the help of, NSString's Size property we can achieve this.

```
let buttonNAme = [" hi ", "welcome", "Login", "Forgot Password ??", "New to here. Sign up??"]
var yPos = CGFloat()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    yPos = 40

    for i in 0..<buttonNAme.count
    {
        self.view.addSubview(addingCustomButton(buttonTitle: buttonNAme[i], buttonFontSize: 15, buttonCount: i))
    }
}

func addingCustomButton(buttonTitle : String, buttonFontSize: CGFloat, buttonCount : Int) -> UIButton
{
    let ownButton = UIButton()

    ownButton.setTitle(buttonTitle, for: UIControlState.normal)


    ownButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: buttonFontSize)

    let buttonTitleSize = (buttonTitle as NSString).size(attributes: [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: buttonFontSize + 1)])

    ownButton.frame.size.height = buttonTitleSize.height * 2
    ownButton.frame.size.width = buttonTitleSize.width
    ownButton.frame.origin.x = 30

    yPos = yPos + (ownButton.frame.size.height) + 10

    ownButton.frame.origin.y = yPos 

    ownButton.tintColor = UIColor.white
    ownButton.backgroundColor = .brown

    ownButton.tag = buttonCount

    ownButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.darkGray, for: UIControlState.highlighted)
    ownButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ownButtonAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    return ownButton
}

func ownButtonAction(sender: UIButton)
{
    print("\n\n Title  \(sender.titleLabel?.text)  TagNum    \(sender.tag)")
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just Constraint it's origin, and the size will fit it's button title